# How to put some comment-like text in a formula?

Tags: plain-tex, text-manipulation

I have the following formula:

```
$$\bot \dashv\vdash \bot \land A  /* not derivable */$$
```

But the phrase `/* not derivable */` doesn't show correctly. For example
there is space between `/` and `*`, but no space between `not` and `derivable`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be using plain TeX so I'll stick to that, you can use `\hbox` to get back into text mode

```
  $$\bot \dashv\vdash \bot \land A  \qquad \hbox{/* not derivable */}$$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an embedded version, you can go:

```
$\bot \dashv\vdash \bot \land A $ not derivable
```